# Advice on User Permissions (Mac OS 10.8.3)

Tags: macos, mac, permissions, dropbox

My first post here, so apologies for any missing information but I will try to cover as much as possible. In short, I am trying to allow two users access to a folder (and files) in one users Dropbox. However, I seem to be having issues maintaining my settings.

I have two admin users setup; one is my main (frequently used) account - let's call this User A. This account is linked with my Dropbox, where all the files I need are kept, and synced to Dropbox. The other user, lets call it User B, is one I use for one application only - Apple Logic Pro 9.

I need User B to have access to a folder within User A's Dropbox folder, with read and write access. I have done this via the "Get Info" menu and added User B with Read & Write access, which I thought had solved the problem. However, it seems I am unable to save a file created in User A when logged into User B.

For example, I create "Test.logic" under User A, and give User B R&W access. I then sign into User B and open the file no problem. However, once I've made changes in User B I get an error when saving, stating I do not have the correct permissions.

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

User B must have at least Read access to the overall Dropbox folder itself - which you must have done to even see in there.

He then needs Read/write access to the sub-folder **&** the file inside that.

Having read/write to the file but not the enclosing folder will give the error you're seeing.

Every time you create a new file with User A, you will need to change the access to add User B to it & vice versa.

---

Might be far simpler to use a folder on a non-boot volume set to 'Ignore ownership'
You can then make a symlink to the folder, then move that to Dropbox & all the issues disappear.
[Aliases don't work on Dropbox, symlinks do]

Terminal method to make symlinks - [How to Create and Use Symlinks on a Mac](https://gigaom.com/2011/04/27/how-to-create-and-use-symlinks-on-a-mac/)

Much simpler app to add making symlinks as a Service from the right-click menu - [SymbolicLinker](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/10433/symboliclinker)

Once made, just Cmd/drag it to your Dropbox folder.
Done.